# Is there an option to filter VMs based on network in Azure Java SDK?

Tags: azure

I tried listing the VMs based on Resource Groups but i want to list the VMs based on network.

Can someone help me with this?

```
PagedList<VirtualMachine> resourceGroupVMs = 
    azure.virtualMachines()
    .listByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I known, all of Azure SDK APIs are just calling the related REST APIs. So according to the [REST API references for Virtual Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines), as below, you see there is not an API to list VMs by network.

[image]

Note: The [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/list) API in the figure above is to list VMs by resource group as the description said,

> Lists all of the virtual machines in the specified resource group. Use the nextLink property in the response to get the next page of virtual machines.

So the workaround in Java to list VMs by network is to use `azure.virtualmachines().listAll()` to list all VMs and filter the results with the network profile for echo VM to get those you want.